# How do I remove page margins in Word?

Tags: microsoft-word

I would like to remove this dotted line around the editable area of the page. It was added by a macro, so I am not sure what it is called and where I remove it.

[image]

Comment: That looks exactly like openoffice does, which is one reason i use abiword or office instead

Comment: Yes, this makes it ever so irritating:)

Comment: FYI, here's the template that did it: http://www.springer.com/authors/book+authors?SGWID=0-154102-12-417900-0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Navigate to...

> File > Options > Advanced > Show Document Content

...then uncheck the `Show Text Boundaries` option

Answer (score 1):

Go to the **Page Layout** tab and click **Page Borders**

[image: Page layout]

Click **None**, the **OK**.

[image: Page Borders]

Comment: Thank you bu this does not help. This border is not a property of the document (it will not be printed), but is rather some option in Word that makes it display all documets like this.

Answer (score 0):

in word 2007 and may be in 2010 you may follow this:

select marginated text> page  layout>margins>custom margins>layout>Border> None
I hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

Good day.
If you are the user of MS WORD 2007 then:

Open an MS word file. 
Then Press OFFICE BUTTON
Then WORD OPTIONS,
Then ADVANCED,
Then  scroll through vertical scroll bar and you will find the heading 
"SHOW DOCUMENT CONTENT" and under this you will find "SHOW TEXT BOUNDARIES" and then UNCHECK the box allocated for "Show text boundaries" and you will see you text boundary disappears. Hope this serves your purpose. Take care. 
Tarek, Bangladesh

Answer (score 0):

I was going to add this as a comment to CJM's answer but I thought that a comparative screenshot would be useful.

Speaking from the far distant future (and for the benefit of others who are also here many years later after searching for "Show Text Boundaries"), the behaviour of the checkbox mentioned in CJM's answer (File > Options > Advanced > Show Document Content > Show Text Boundaries) was changed in Word 2013 to the infuriation of many Word power users.

In 2010 it would show a boundary outline around the text-containing part of a page (as shown in the screenshot of the question). That is, it would exclude margins, etc so that you would have a clear idea of how much space you have for adding text.

If the section of the document was defined as having multiple columns, the outline would appear around the text-containing part of each column. Similarly it would appear around the text-containing part of a text box.

In Word 2013 it was "fixed" so that Word now shows a boundary outline around each paragraph. The sole exception is a text box, where the boundary is still around the entire text-containing part of the object as shown below.

Thus, if you're here in a post-2013 world you will be seeing something very different.

[image: Screenshot of boundary outline in Office 365 from 2021]